# Prove $\overline{A \cup B} = \overline A \cup \overline B$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, proof-writing

Prove $\overline{A \cup B} = \overline A \cup \overline B$ (where $A,B$ are arbitrary sets, and $\overline S$ means the smallest closed set containing $S$).  *Proofs for this are readily available; please verify and critique* my *proof.*

**Proof:** We first prove that a limit point $\ell$ of $A \cup B$ must either be a limit point of $A$ or a limit point of $B$.

For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an open disc $D_\epsilon(\ell)$ with at least one point in $A \cup B$.  Suppose there exists $k > 0$ where there does not exist an open disc $D_k(\ell)$ with at least one point in $A$.  Then, for any $\epsilon \leq k$, there exists an open disc $D_\epsilon(\ell)$ with at least one point in $B$, and $\ell$ is therefore a limit point of $B$.  Conversely, if for all $k > 0$ there exists an open disc $D_k(\ell)$ with at least one point in $A$, $\ell$ is a limit point of $A$.

The result then follows from the definition of union, closure, and limit point, and the fact that the closure of a set is equal to the union of the set and its limit points.*

By induction, this can be extended to any finite collection of sets.  However, it cannot be extended to an infinite collection of sets, as evidenced by $0 \in \overline{\{1/1\}\cup  \{1/2\} \cup \{1/3\}...}$ but not in any $\overline{\{1/n\}}$.

---

***Update:** *The comments requested that I write out the part I asserted was trivial.  I still maintain that it is indeed trivial and should not be written.  Do you agree?* If $\ell \in \overline{A \cup B}$, then either $\ell \in A \cup B$ or $\ell \in (A \cup B)'$ (with $S'$ meaning the limit points of $S$).  In the first case, $\ell$ is trivially in $\overline A \cup \overline B$, as any set is a subset of its closure.  The second case is addressed by the above. Conversely, if $\ell \in \overline A \cup \overline B$, then either $\ell \in A \cup B$, in which case $\ell \in \overline{A \cup B}$, or $\ell \in A' \cup B'$.  Since $S \subset U \implies S' \subset U'$, the latter case implies $\ell \in \overline{A \cup B}$ as well.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\Bbb R$? Of $\Bbb R^n$? Of a metric space? Of a topological space?

Comment: $0 \not\in \overline{\{1/1\}\cup  \{1/2\} \cup \{1/3\}...\cup\{1/n\}}$. That's a finite union. It's the union of $n$ sets. If you meant to write an infinite product don't write the last term.

Comment: I think it is true in general not only for metric spaces.

Comment: @jjagmath Although I had in mind $\mathbb{R}$, I believe my proof is correct for any metric space, and could be gently revised to include any topological space.

Comment: "The result then follows from the definition of union, closure, and limit point, and the fact that the closure of a set is equal to the union of the set and its limit points." I'd like to see this spelled out more specifically. You've done the work.  If we notate $dM=$ the set of limit points of $M$ the $\overline{A\cup B}=d(A\cup B)\cup(A\cup B)\subseteq(dA\cup dB)=(A\cup dA)\cup (B\cup dA)=\overline A\cup \overline B$.  Hmm I suppose we ought to prove $d(A\cup B) =dA\cup dB$ and not merely a subset but that's trivial; any limit point of $M$ has to be a limit point if $M\cup X$ for any $X$.

Comment: Hmm.... maybe it's not all that trivial to assume that if $l$ is a limit point of $A$ or $l$ is a limit of $B$ then it is a limit point of $A\cup B$.  Your proof of the other direction seems to be no more or less easy or as obvious.  If you only prove a limit point of $A\cup B$ is a limit point of $A$ or of $B$ but not that a limit point of $A$ or of $B$ is a limit point of $A\cup B$ then you have proven $\overline{A\cup B}\subseteq \overline A \cup \overline B$ but not actually equality.

Comment: I wrote out the part I claimed was trivial and am now further convinced of such.  Please review and comment.

Comment: Both the first answer and some comments note that "a limit point of $A \cup B$ is a limit point of $A$ or a limit point of $B$" proves $\overline{A \cup B} \subseteq \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$. So you should at least comment why "a limit point of $A$ or of $B$ is a limit point of $A \cup B$" to prove $\overline{A} \cup \overline{B} \subseteq \overline{A \cup B}$ and therefore the sets are equal, though I think this is the easier direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some critiques:

1.) I think the organization of the proof could be improved. For simple problems where you are showing two sets are equal, I generally think it's best to just show the two sets are subsets of each other. Your first paragraph sort of shows that $\overline{A \cup B} \subseteq \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$, but it's good to make these things very clear (especially at the level of math where you're being asked this as an exercise). You also **did not** show the reverse containment.

2.) You end with "The result then follows from the definition of union, closure, and limit point, and the fact that the closure of a set is equal to the union of the set and its limit points.*" While you remarked why this is "trivial", if you write the proof in a more structured way you don't need to appeal to all these things to conclude your argument. From the view of a reader, when I read "the result follows by XYZ" and the XYZ is a long list of definitions, observations, etc. it would take me a minute to figure out how to put these together (worse yet, that I may lack trust you know how these things should fit together).

3.) This is a matter of notation/style, but usually $k$ (when meant to refer to a number) is reserved for integers, whereas you use it to mean a real number. In theory it doesn't matter, but sticking with conventional notation often improves clarity.

4.) You give the definition of $\overline{S}$ to be the smallest closed set containing $S$, but then use the fact that $x \in \overline{S}$ means $x \in S$ or $x$ is a limit point of $S$. Of course, this fact is extremely well-known, but if you are just working with the original definition you should at least mention that we can easily show the second fact is an equivalent definition of closure.

EDIT: As requested, how I would write the proof:

We'll do the proof assuming $A$ and $B$ are subsets of metric space $X$. For $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x \in X$, we denote $B_\varepsilon(x)$ to be the open ball of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at $x$. We'll use the stated fact that $\overline{S} = S \cup S'$, where $S'$ is the set of limit points of $S$, for any $S \subseteq X$.

**Proof:** Let $p \in \overline{A \cup B}$, so either $p \in A \cup B$ or $p \in (A \cup B)'$. In the former case, $p \in \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$, since any set is a subset of its closure. In the latter case, let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $p \in (A \cup B)'$, we know $B_\varepsilon(p) \cap (A\cup B)$ contains a point, $q$, distinct from $p$. We have:
$$
B_\varepsilon(p) \cap (A \cup B) = (B_\varepsilon(p) \cap A) \cup (B_\varepsilon(p) \cap B),
$$
so either $q \in B_\varepsilon(p) \cap A$ or $q \in B_\varepsilon(p) \cap B$. In other words, $p$ is either a limit point of $A$ or a limit point of $B$. This establishes $\overline{A\cup B} \subseteq \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$.

Conversely, let $p \in \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$, so $p \in \overline{A}$ or $p \in \overline{B}$. Without loss of generality, assume $p \in \overline{A}$. If $p \in A$, then $p \in \overline{A \cup B}$ immediately, so suppose $p \in A'$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$, and consider $B_\varepsilon(p) \cap (A \cup B)$. Since $p \in A'$, there exists $q \in B_\varepsilon(p) \cap A$ distinct from $p$. But then $q \in B_\varepsilon(p) \cap (A \cup B)$ as well, so $p \in (A\cup B)'$, and consequently $p \in \overline{A\cup B}$. This establishes $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} \subseteq \overline{A \cap B}$. QED

Comment: @SRobertJames If helpful, I am happy to write out a version of the proof to address the points I made!

Comment: All very helpful points.  And yes, please write out that proof!

Comment: @SRobertJames Done!

Comment: I certainly appreciate how this proof addresses all the points noted.  But it seems to me to pay a price: The key insight to the proof is hidden.  What needs to be true for $\overline{A \cup B}$ to equal $\overline A \cup \overline B$? The answer is "A limit point of a union is a limit point of one of its components."   Prove that and the rest immediately follows.  I believe a good exposition should center around that.  Do you agree?

Comment: As a student, I'd struggle with the exposition given, because the key insight (which is not obvious to me) is interspersed amongst the more mechanical steps.

Comment: What you're saying is true, and that's definitely another way to prove it! Often there are many ways to prove things. I actually debated including the exact remark you made as part of the proof, but decided against it because I figured having the detailed (albeit mechanical) steps written out was more relevant. But using what you said, I could replace the second paragraph with $p \in \overline{A}$ implies $p \in \overline{A \cup B}$ since $\overline{A} \subseteq (A \cup A') \cup (B \cup B')  = (A \cup B) \cup (A' \cup B') = \overline{A \cup B}$ since $A' \cup B' = (A \cup B)'$ by the remark.

Comment: A limit point of a **finite** union is a limit point of one of its components. You could certainly rearrange the suggested proof so that your "key insight" statement is asserted early, maybe even called a lemma. I don't see that as a huge improvement, myself.

Comment: I used your introduction of $B_\varepsilon(q) \cap (A cup B)$ (which greatly simplifies the logic) as well as your other recommendations to write a revised proof (below) which I believe still focuses the key insight.  Please q.v.

Comment: "so either q∈Bε(p)∩A or q∈Bε(p)∩B. In other words, p is either a limit point of A or a limit point of B" Is this a good proof? We need to show that there's a q in A for _all_ $\varepsilon$; yet all we've shown so far is that for a particular $\varepsilon$ there's a q in A or B - but if we jump back and forth between A and B for different $\varepsilon$, we haven't shown it's a limit point of either!  That is, we've shown "For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a set A or B..." but what we need to show is "There exists a set A or B such that for all $\varepsilon > 0$...".

Comment: Please note: when you want to show something holds "for all $\varepsilon > 0$", you pick an arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$ and show the statement holds. That's exactly what I've done.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing on ccroth's proof and recommendations, while addressing the concerns I raised (in the comments), I present the revised approach below.  Please critique.

**Lemma:** $(A \cup B)' = A' \cup B'.$

Proof: For any $p \in (A \cup B)'$, we have that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a point $q \neq p$ such that $q \in B_\varepsilon(p) \cap (A \cup B)$, implying that $q \in B_\varepsilon(p) \cap A$ or $q \in B_\varepsilon(p) \cap B$.  Conversely, for any $p \in A'$, we have that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a point $q \neq p$ such that $q \in (B_\varepsilon(p) \cap A) \subset (B_\varepsilon(p) \cap (A \cup B))$.  A similar argument applies to $p \in B'$.

With this, the asserted equality becomes straightforward (noting that any set is a subset of its closure):

(1) $p \in \overline{A \cup B} \implies p \in \overline A \cup \overline B$.  Since $\overline S = S \cup S'$, either $p \in (A \cup B)$ or $p \in (A \cup B)'$.  In the first case, $p$ is immediately in $\overline A \cup \overline B$, and in the second case, our lemma shows this as well.

(2) $p \in \overline A \cup \overline B \implies p \in \overline{A \cup B}$.  Without loss of generality, assume $p \in \overline A = A \cup A'$.  $A$ is clearly a subset of $\overline{A \cup B}$, and our lemma shows $A' \subset (A \cup B)' \subset \overline{A \cup B}$ as well.

Comment: Your proof of the lemma is correct, albeit I recommend you see my comment concerning the $\varepsilon$. When proving stuff you don't want to regurgitate definitions, you want to *use* definitions. That means your first line should ideally read: "Let $p \in (A \cup B)'$, and let $\varepsilon >0$ be given." Then you go on to show that $p$ is either in $A'$ or $B'$, and this is valid since you picked arbitrary $\varepsilon$.

As last part, you can simply observe: $\overline{A \cup B} = (A \cup B) \cup (A\cup B)' = (A \cup A') \cup (B \cup B') = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$, by the lemma.

Comment: @ccroth Very helpful.  It still seems to me, though, that this isn't enough.  We can show that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, $q \in B_\varepsilon(p)$ is in $A$ or is in $B$.  But what if e.g. for $\varepsilon = 1/2$, then $q$ is in  $A$, but for $\varepsilon = 1/4$, $q$ is in B? Then we haven't proven that p is a limit point of _either_ set.  The only solution I see uses the fact that $\varepsilon < \delta \implies B_\varepsilon \subset B_\delta$.

Comment: @ccroth I wrote a _third_ proof below, which uses your recommendation to apply (not repeat) definitions, and addresses my concern about switching between A and B.  Can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma:** $(A \cup B)' = A' \cup B'.$

**Proof:** Clearly, if $p$ is a limit point of $A$ or of $B$, then $p$ is a limit point of $A \cup B$.  We now prove the converse: Let $p \in (A \cup B)'$.  If for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $q \neq p$ such that $q\in B_\varepsilon(p) \cap A$, then $p$ is a limit point of $A$.

Otherwise, there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ where no such $q$ exists.  Then for any $\delta$ such that $0 < \delta < \varepsilon$, $B_\delta(p) \subset B_\varepsilon(p)$, and thus no $q \neq p$ exists in $B_\delta(p) \cap A$.  But for any such $\delta$, a $q \neq p$ must exist in $B_\delta(p) \cap (A \cup B)$, since $p$ is a limit point of $A \cup B$.  Consequently, $q \in B_\delta(p) \cap B$ for all such $\delta$, and $p$ is a limit point of $B$.

From this lemma, we have $\overline{A \cup B} = (A \cup B) \cup (A \cup B)' = A \cup B \cup A' \cup B' = \overline A \cup \overline B.$

---

**Discussion:** The proof has two components of note:

1. Recognizing that the contribution is entirely in the lemma, and, once separated out, the entire proof follows immediately from it.
2. Making use of the fact that balls of decreasing radius are subsets of each other.  I maintain that without this fact, the proofs above are *not* correct.

Comment: I think I see where the confusion is. Yes the point you make is correct, I guess for me it becomes a little bit redundant because once you show that **any** neighborhood of $p$ contains a distinct point $q$ belonging to $A$ or $B$, it's clear that $p$ has to be a limit point of *at least* one of these sets (note that we have not assumed $A \neq B$). You of course gave the details, which are correct, by showing $p \in (A \cup B)'$ and $p \not \in A'$ implies $p \in B'$.

Comment: If we were to be perfectly technical, you would say "since $p \not \in A'$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $B_\delta(p) \cap A \subseteq \{p\}$. Let $\varepsilon >0$ and WLOG take $\varepsilon < \delta$. Since there exists $q \in B_\varepsilon(p) \cap (A \cup B)$ distinct from $p$, we know $q \in B$..." then the argument follows.